# Why does Windows Phone 7.1 SDK install VS 2010 express?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to install Windows Phone 7.1 SDK from

https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

I don't understand why does this stupid installer try to install VS 2010 express when I already have VS 2010 Ultimate with SP1 installed? Is there any way to stop it from downloading this and installing it unnecessarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack, It is not stupid. It was doing its job :). VS 2010 Express is a dedicated IDE for the Windows Phone application developement. And it works with or without any other VS version(including VS Ultimate). VS 2010 Express contains the SDK required for the WP application development.

So, nothing to worry. Go ahead with your download and installation.